# How do I use LINQ to parse XML with child elements of the same name?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

**Background Information:**
In the past, I have been picking up a collection of XML files and iterating through each XML file, parsing it, passing string data to a data transfer object and passing the object into a database.

Before, my XML looked like this.

```
<messages>
    <message>
        <title>Red Wall</title>
        <summary>This is a good article</summary>
        <ISBN>13546846545464</ISBN>
    </message>
</messages>
```

Here, I only have one  element. So, I would parse the XML by using LINQ and retrieve the subsequent elements(title, summary, isbn). Then I would initialize/instantiate an object, assign its properties to the values I retrieved, and send it along.

Now my XML looks like this:

```
<messages>
<message>
    <title>Red Wall</title>
    <summary>This is a good article</summary>
    <ISBN>13546846545464</ISBN>
</message>

<message>
    <title>Blue Wall</title>
    <summary>This is not a good article</summary>
    <ISBN>15648465416</ISBN>
</message>
</messages>
```

I now have two (or more)  elements in my XML file, and for each one I need to **1)** identify that there are multiple  elements and **2)** for each  create a separate DTO to hold the data that I parse.

**My question is:** How do I parse XML with multiple  tags and identify each one I encounter as being separate from the other?

**Final Note:** While parsing, I need to be able to instantiate a DTO to capture the information I get returned back.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: For each file you need to identify if or if not it has multiple elements before you attempt to parse it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Grab the element you want and use your select to populate the dto from the child items.  Something like this not tested

```
XElement ele = loaded.Element("messages");    
dtos = from item in ele.Descendants("message")
    select new DTO() {title = item.Element(title).value ,... };
```

Comment: I am new to LINQ. Did not know you could instantiate through the select statement. Sexy. For each message then: how do I add the DTOs to a list? I need to build a list of DTOs per file and return that out to the method that hits the DB. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @fullNelson: the code above is adding each DTO to an `IEnumerable` collection `dtos`. You can call `.ToList()`, `.ToArray()` etc on this object directly

Comment: @rerun or @kaveman : I added the code and tailored it to my situation, however, when I make the assignment `List<ReviewDTC> reviews = dtos.ToList<ReviewDTO>();` it states that the count of the reviews list is 0. So it seems like rerun's code isn't building the objects. Is that possible?

Comment: is it casting correctly? what is the count of the returned list using the extension method?  Also you can put a break point in the constructor of the object and check to see its being called.

Comment: Yeah, there are no errors on the cast. It cites that the returned list is null. The full method (minus the signature) I am using is below in a response to JRack's solution.

Comment: if you have a breakpoint in the ReviewDTC constructor does it get called

Comment: No, its giving me a null reference exception on the breakpoint.

Comment: Its working fine now. PEBKAC on my part. Thank you and everyone else for your help. Case closed!

Answer (score 0):

The select statement above is going to return an IEnumerable<DTO>, which is a sequence of DTO objects.  For every message node it finds in the XML, it will create a DTO object and add it to the sequence returned.  If your goal is just to iterate over all the DTOs, you're already there.  If you actually need a List<DTO>, there is a constructor on the generic List object that takes an IEnumerable<T>, so you could pass in the "dtos" you received from the select statement and have a List.

Comment: I have this code now, and it seems my reviews list is null when it reaches the return statement. Am I missing something you are saying here? `XElement root = XElement.Load(fileInProcessingName);
       var dtos = from item in root.Descendants("message")
       select new ReviewDTC()
       {
        Summary = item.Element("summary").Value ,
        Isbn = item.Element("ISBN").Value ,
        PubDate = item.Element("PublicationDate").Value
       };

List<ReviewDTC> reviews = dtos.ToList<ReviewDTC>();

            return reviews;
        }`

Comment: it looks like you aren't actually passing the values from `item.Element(..).Value` into a constructor for `ReviewDTC`. Before you call `List<ReviewDTC> reviews = dtos.ToList<ReviewDTC>` take a look at the `reviews` IEnumerable in a breakpoint, and see if it's getting populated as you expect.

Comment: Hmm... It looks like I just have a blank constructor on my ReviewDTC class. You are right, in the case of the code above, I am not actually initializing the object am I?

Comment: I got it worked out. As usual, a pebkac on my part. Thanks for your added help.